# How to decrypt Windows vault element with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am making a vault viewer utility. So, I need to decrypt Windows vault. I know there are `Policy.vpol`, `.vcrd` and `.vsch` files, but actually how to decrypt it with C++?

Comment: I hope it's not easy... I mean, I assume (and hope) that there is not an easy way to break what is supposed to be a security feature

Comment: Of course, i read an article on zena forencis: http://blog.digital-forensics.it/2016/01/windows-revaulting.html, but couldn't actually do it..

Comment: Find the Decryption algorithm first. without the key that's impossible. it is encrypted for a reason.

Comment: It's not impossible. Back home, I knew this kid who could pick off Womp rats... But seriously, it just takes a lot of time if you don't know the algorithm and keys.

Comment: Typically one never attempts to read system files, but instead use Windows API functions to enumerate such things.

Comment: This is not really related to C++, but to the WinAPI, which may be used from C and other languages. I would avoid tagging it as such.

Comment: That link you provided already contains python code that decrypts the data.. why don't you use that? Or translate it to C++ yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You could only enumerate them with [`CredEnumerate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincred/nf-wincred-credenumeratew) like:

```
void Enumerate()
{
    DWORD Count;
    PCREDENTIALW *Credential;
    //Now enumerate all http stored credentials....
    if (CredEnumerateA(NULL, CRED_ENUMERATE_ALL_CREDENTIALS, &Count, &Credential))
    {

        for (int i = 0; i<Count; i++)
        {
            //print Credential[i] information
        } 
        CredFree(Credential);
    }
}
```

Or retrieve the credential with [`CredRead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincred/nf-wincred-credreadw):

```
void Retrieve()
{
        PCREDENTIALW pcred;
        BOOL ok = ::CredReadW(L"FOO/account", CRED_TYPE_GENERIC, 0, &pcred);
        wprintf(L"CredRead() - errno %d\n", ok ? 0 : ::GetLastError());
        if (!ok) 
            return ;
        wprintf(L"Read username = '%s', password='%S' (%d bytes)\n",
            pcred->UserName, (char*)pcred->CredentialBlob, pcred->CredentialBlobSize);
        CredFree(pcred);
}
```

You are not able to get password information for domain passwords if you do not have any key.